# Passing a value to a Single-line text box with a click

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Please enter address:  
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Some Address" style="width:350px">
    <input type="submit" name="GO" id="GO" value="GO!">
</form>

1: address 1

2: address 2

3: address 3

4: address 4
```

By default the single-line text box has value as "Some Address".

But there are other address below that form like above. Such as:

1: address 1

2: address 2

3: address 3

4: address 4

etcs...

I want to click the address 1 and replace "Some address" by a new Value which is "Address 1" and so on with other addresses.

Those address are generated from a mysql database using php.

How do I proceed?

Comment: _"But there are other address below that form."_ Really? I don't see any.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you are getting where I am approaching. But how do I make the address clickable? and replace it with Some Addresses. Those address 1, address 2 are dynamically generated via db using php.

Answer (score 0):

If you opted to use jQuery, you can just use `click` event, then get the value and change the textbox value. Consider this example: [**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cWxV5y)

```
<?php

$result = array();
// sample select pseudo code since you didn't provided the db fetching
// $con = new msqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
// $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT address_name FROM table_blah_blah_blah_address');
// while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
//  $result[] = $row;
// }
// lets save it contains addresses fetched from db (SAMPLE!)
$result = array(
    array('name' => 'address 1'),
    array('name' => 'address 2'),
    array('name' => 'address 3'),
    array('name' => 'address 4'),
);

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Please enter address:
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Some Address" style="width:350px" />
    <input type="reset" value="Revert" />
    <input type="submit" name="GO" id="GO" value="GO!">
</form>

<div class="addresses">
<?php foreach($result as $line_num => $address): ?>
    <a href="#" class="clickable_address" data-value="<?php echo $address['name']; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php echo ++$line_num.'. '. $address['name']; ?><br/></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable_address').on('click', function(){
        $('#address').val($(this).data('value'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the items from your database call into links, and use the javascript with the onclick attribute;

```
//A mock of your php code - the actual db call is not shown in your question
<?php while($row = db::getline()): ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="yourfunc('<?php echo $row['col'];?>');return false;"><?php echo $row['col'];?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
yourfunc(val){
    document.getElementById("address").value = val;
}
</script>
```